# Could anybody help by applying a secure multiparty secret sharing scheme?

Tags: protocol-design, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, entropy, group-theory

Suppose that we have a multi-secret sharing scheme as it is described in the  [literature](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48658-5_17.pdf)

Let there be $I$ agents and say that $S$ is the space of the (uniform) random variables $s=(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_I)\in S$ such that the share $s_1$ is known to $P_1$, $s_2$ is known to $P_2$ and so on. Could someone propose an appropriate multi secret sharing scheme? Every agent $i$ wants to share $s_i$ in such a way that it is not easy computable from a small group of players (I do not know if an $(|I|-1,|I|-1)$-threshold scheme can be applied)

Could anyone provide explicitly a proof? Maybe it seems easy, but I am a bit confused where to start or how to do the maths. I would appreciate it if it is convenient for him/her who could give a proof to use $+$ or $\otimes$ and $mod$ schemes from group theory instead of polynomial explanation because it seems more simple for my understanding.

Comment: @moderators I have totally re-edited my question, is there a choice where I can re-post it?

Comment: @JAAAY I almost totally re-edited my question

Comment: I would recommend you to read https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07197.pdf but an answer has to be given here also.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo seriously, the way that they write, all of those who are doing research in cryptography is quite non-efficient. For example, we know in general that $x\underbrace{\to}_{f} y$, which means that $f(x)=y$, but instead they are using an inverse arrow, $x_i\rightarrow inv(u_i)$ totally a mess. Especially when instead of inv you have a function like $VSS_{put}(s)=...$, well this function  $VSS_{put}$ must have some properties what are they? None clarifies them. And the latter, they all say that $P_i$ shares $s_i$ among $N-\{i\}$ or $(n-1)$ agents....

Comment: So what is that every other player $j$ leans form $i$ so as if all $j$ players do a computations they can compute $s_i$. None writes explicitly that for example, player $j$ learns $x_j$ and all of them exchange their $x_j'$s and compute for example $x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots\oplus x_{n-1}=s_i$, namely $x_j'$s are the puzzle to reconstruct $s_i$

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo I do not mean to offend you. It is very nice that you have some kind of help to give. The problem is in the general with how all these in computer science write the maths...fully complex while everything could be simple

Comment: Yes, in science sometimes to show some things you have to hide others.